# Ubuntu Restarts When HDMI Is Plugged In

Tags: 14.04, 17.10, hdmi

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 about a week ago and things have been working fine. All of a sudden today my hdmi is not working correctly. When I plug in the hdmi and try to boot, I make it to the login screen. When I try to login, it seems to restart the Ubuntu boot process and takes me back to the login screen. If I remove the hdmi cable and log in, I can get in. If I then plug in the hdmi, it glitches out a little bit and then does the reboot behavior. To my knowledge, nothing has changed since yesterday.

Any idea how I can fix this?

### Update:

I just rolled back (fresh install) to 16.04 and still have the issue of the system crashing and restarting when an HDMI cable is plugged in. I have tried multiple cables and the issue persists.

The odd part is, this is the same machine and same cables I have been using for over 6 months with no issues.

Comment: Try a different HDMI cable. How long is your cable and what HDMI spec type is it?

Comment: I just tried a second hdmi cable and it works, but still went through the restart process which killed all my applications. How can I determine the hdmi spec type?

Comment: If a different HDMI cable didn't work either chances are it's not the cable. The higher the spec rating the more pixels and FPS the cable can handle without failure. It's probably not an issue in your case though. I think it's software related. What exactly I don't know.

Comment: Possibly a hardware error/failure? Anywho, I would definitely check the logs...

Comment: @NerdOfCode Any specific logs you think would be worth while to check?

Comment: I would start off by checking `/var/log/kern.log`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by installing new Nvidia drivers that I'm guessing were deleted with autoremove. So install nvidia-390 and it should work. However, I did get some heating issues with the driver, but that could just be laptop related.